# Browseable attribute and Infragistics WinGrid

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm struggling with the databind behaviour of the Infragistics WinGrid.
It's possible to manually define a data schema (which I'm doing) and it's also possible to tell the grid when binding that I don't want for the grid to display additional bands or columns, even if my data source has them.

```
DisplayLayout.NewBandLoadStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.NewBandLoadStyle.Hide;
DisplayLayout.NewColumnLoadStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.NewColumnLoadStyle.Hide;
```

The problem is that the grid ALWAYS tries to get the value of the property even if it's not in the columns layout. It's possible however use the browseable attribute in the domain object:

```
[Browsable(false)]
```

and the grid will ignore the property (it won't try to use the property getter). But I believe this is a lame workaround. Does anyone know an efficient way to instruct the grid only to get the value for the items defined in the layout.

Many thanks

Comment: Infragistics libraries are a bug depository.  Use the vendor's support forum to get help.

Comment: Your question actually gave me the answer I was looking for [Browsable(false)], so it wouldn't read an expensive property (legacy). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the DisplayLayout of the grid, there is a MaxBandDepth property.  This will limit the number of bands that's shown.

I.e. if you have a heirarchical data source with 2 tables (parent to child relationship) and you set the MaxBandDepth to 1, then only the parent table's information will show.

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for your answer, it was useful, but it's not what I'm looking. My problem is not at that level, but with simple thinks like calculated properties at the parent level. I could replace the properties by getter methods, but I won't be using in my case NHibernate in its full power. The underling problem is that the Infragistics grid is using the bind manager that will always get all properties, I believe the only way to solve my problem is to write my own binding manager.